# generating random colors using angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How to generate random colors in ng-repeat. 
i tried in the following way, but not working.

I am getting error, saying:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

### controller

```
$scope.getRandomColor = function(){
        return {
            borderLeft: '2px solid # '+Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1)
        }       
    };
```

### view

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customerData" class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="contact-box" ng-style="getRandomColor()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to add the random value (random style ) for each element in the customerData array (in javascript).

Comment: the issue in your code in each digest cycle a random color is generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/akbb6car/1/):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <div ng-repeat="customer in customerData" class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="contact-box" ng-style="customer.color">&nbsp; {{customer.name}} got: {{customer.color}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var getRandomColor = function () {
        return {
            borderLeft: '2px solid #' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
        }
    };

    $scope.customerData = [{
        name: "Mike",
        color: getRandomColor()
    }, {
        name: "Tom",
        color: getRandomColor()
    }];

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with `ng-init` and `ng-style`

view:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customerData" class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="contact-box" ng-init="customer.color = getRandomColor()" ng-style="customer.color">
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.getRandomColor = function(){
        return {
            borderLeft: '2px solid # '+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
        }       
    };
```