# Randomly Color Divs inside ng-repeat with unknown number of Items

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have data(say a list of items) and it is coming from $http.get request. I **want** to change the color of divs containing the items under ng-repeat div. The number of items are random.
**My code**
*controller.js*

```
$http.post("ServerUrl")
    .success(function(data) { 
    $scope.data = data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
    alert(err);
    })
```

*template*

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data">
{{data}}
</div>
```

*What I want*
[image]

*What I have tried*
Well I tried to put some colors in $scope and repeated them in template but if I have put 5 color in $scope then it is coloring only 5 div in template(working as expected).
**So I want** a way where I can repeat the color randomly for any number of items returning from $http request.

Comment: I think you have to look this, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326155/generating-random-colors-using-angular-ng-repeat)

Comment: Thanks for this link but this doesn't solve my problem. i am dealing with $http here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define if you want some specific colors and then make them repeat.

```
 $scope.colorCodeArray = [
         "#339E42",
         "#039BE5",
         "#EF6C00",
         "#A1887F",
         "#607D8B",
         "#039BE5",
         "#009688",
    ];


  <div ng-repeat="data in data">
  <div ng-style="{background: colorCodeArray[$index % colorCodeArray.length]}" >{{data}}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, @neda!

Comment: Yeah thats what I am asking about.Can you explain that what *[$index % colorCodeArray.length]* does ?

Comment: $index is index value of the arrays current element(int). So, assume that you get 7th index from data array and your color array have 5 color. This code get colorCodeArray[2] and set your background to this color. @Atula

Comment: For the colors to repeat if colorCodeArray length is less than data length this is there *[$index % colorCodeArray.length]*

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

The trick here is the `$index`, that tells you in which the iteration is.

```js
(function() {
  
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  
  app.controller('MainController', MainController);
  
  function MainController() {
    
    var self = this;
    self.data = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR'];
    self.style = function(index) {
      
      var red = index * 40;
      var green = index * 40;
      var blue = index * 40;
      
      var color = 'color: rgb('+red+', '+green+', '+blue+')';
      return color;
      
      }
    
    }
  
  })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="dz in vm.data" style="{{ vm.style($index) }}">
    {{dz}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eg.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp" lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Random Color</title>


<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<style>

div {
   border: "2px solid black";
}

</style>    

<script>
     var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
     app.controller('MyCtrlr', function ($scope, $http) {


                      //$http.get("YOUR_AJAX_URL").success(function(response){

                         $scope.randomColor = function(){
                           var color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
                           return color;

                         }

                         $scope.data = [111, 222, 333, 444, 555];

                         alert($scope.data);

                       //});

 });



  </script>

</head>



 <body ng-controller="MyCtrlr" >


    <div ng-repeat="data in data" style="background-color: {{randomColor()}}">
        Color {{data}}
    </div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Jenson, would you mind explain what does `((1<<24)*Math.random()|0)` it do? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielCâmara It's all about generating a random Hex color code. `<<` means Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeroes from the right.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that you can try:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      $scope.getRandomColor = function() {
        var randomNumber = getRandomNumber(0, $scope.colors.length - 1);
        console.log(randomNumber)
        return $scope.colors[randomNumber];
      };

      $scope.colors = ['#673ab7', '#3f51b5', '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688'];
      $scope.boxData = [{
        name: "Box 1"
      }, {
        name: "Box 2"
      }, {
        name: "Box 3"
      }, {
        name: "Box 4"
      }];

    }
  ]);

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

```css
.contact-box {
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  dispaly: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="b in boxData">
    <div class="contact-box" ng-style="{'background-color': getRandomColor() }">{{ b.name }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akbb6car/19/)